# Checking heights in elm

Tags: events, height, elm

I have the following html structure:

```
div.mainContainer
   button
   div.container
      div.block
         text
      div.block
         text
```

`.block`s are editable (`contenteditable`), so you can add text.

When you click on button, a new `.block` is added at first position inside first `.container`,

I would like to check height of `.container` and when its height is bigger than 400px, new container should be added and move latest blocks of first `.container` to the second one until first `.containter` is not bigger than 400px. And so on if it is necessary a third `.container`.

My Elm application has the following model:

```
type alias Model =
    { content: List String}
```

My views:

```
view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div [ class "mainContainer"]
        (buttonView :: (viewContainer model) :: [])

viewContainer : Model -> Html Msg
viewContainer model =
    div [ class "container" ]
        (map blockView model.content)

buttonView : Html Msg
buttonView =
    button [onClick NewBlock] [ text "New block"]

blockView : String -> Html Msg
blockView contentText = 
    div [ class "block", contenteditable True]
        [ text contentText ]
```

I start with two blocks:

```
init : () -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
init _ =
    ({ content= "Lorem"::"Ipsum"::[]}, Cmd.none )
```

Button click add new block to the model:

```
newBlock : Model -> Model
newBlock model =
    { model | content = "example"::model.content}
```

`Msg`type and `update` functions:

```
type Msg
    = CheckHeights
    | NewBlock


update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        CheckHeights ->
            ( model, Cmd.none ) -- How do it?
        NewBlock ->
            (model |> newBlock, Cmd.none)
```

I think the best approach is using subscriptions (`onKeyDown` event) but I do not know how as you can check in above `update` function.

```
subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions _ =
    onKeyDown (Decode.succeed CheckHeights)
```

Here you can check my code: https://ellie-app.com/8KCV7jjT94va1

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Browser.Dom.getElement`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/browser/latest/Browser-Dom#getElement) to get the dimensions of an element, but you'll have to to give the element a unique `id`. Once you've done that, this is how your `msg` type and `update` function can be adapted to use it:

```
type Msg
    = CheckHeights
    | NewBlock
    | GotElement (Result Browser.Dom.Error Browser.Dom.Element)

update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        CheckHeights ->
            ( model, Task.attempt GotElement (Browser.Dom.getElement "some-block-id") )

        GotElement (Ok element) ->
            -- Do whatever you need to do with the dimensions of element
            ( model, Cmd.none )

        GotElement (Err _) ->
            -- Handle error
            ( model, Cmd.none )

        NewBlock ->
            ( model |> newBlock, Cmd.none )
```